# How do I reverse PNG filters?

Tags: php, png

I know you can apply PNG filters, like PNG_FILTER_UP to the imagepng() function, but how can I reverse that output. Is there a function to undo the filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to *undo* anything. The "filter" specifies  one of the [five possible error prediction filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#9Filters) used internally by the PNG encoding algorithm. The decoder discovers it (the stream includes the info about what filter was used for each line) and it can decode the image, and that's all. Perhaps you are thinking of the "filter" as some kind of image processing, but it's not, it does not alter the image at all.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of them as transforming the data. I'll review my problem for another issue. Thank you.